# Json image parse error in ios.

Tags: iphone, json, image

Hi I am new to programming. 
My problem is that i can not parse images. The images need to be parsed into a list with text.

I am using JSONKit to parse json. I have an older version of xcode and only have simulator 4.3.

I can parse text but not images. I have looked at a few examples on how to parse images but was not able to do it correctly.

The json I want to parse:

```
{[{"n_id":"1","n_name":"Green","n_text":"this is test","Image":"dasdas.jpg"}]}
```

I think i need to use something like this

```
NSData *img=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:img];
```

But i have no idea how to incorporate it into my code. 
I am a bit lost.

Thanks in advance

////Json2ViewController.h

```
@interface Json2ViewController : UIViewController {
NSArray * list;
NSString * content;
NSString * many;
NSString * thumbNail;
NSMutableArray *studName;
NSMutableArray *ntext;
NSMutableArray *imagesArray;
NSArray *images;
}
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* studName;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* ntext;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* imagesArray;
```

//Json2ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSData * JSONdata =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com"]];


 if([JSONdata length] == 0){
 [JSONdata release];
 return;
 }

NSArray *students =[JSONdata objectFromJSONData];

studName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ntext = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *student in students)
{
    content = [student objectForKey:@"n_name"];
    if(content)
       [studName addObject:content];

    many = [student objectForKey:@"n_text"];
    if(many)
        [ntext addObject:many];

    images = [student objectForKey:@"Image"];
    if(images)
        [imagesArray addObject:images];

    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


cell.imageView.image = = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [studName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [ntext objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: The JSON you want to parse is invalid, its missing a property.

Comment: hey you need yo paas some url to get imagem instead of image name.

Answer (score 1):

Get absolute server path of image from Json like :

> https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png

or

define base server path like :

```
#define baseImgurl  @"https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/"
```

join with

```
NSString *imgurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseImgurl,[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

cell.imageView.image = [[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgurl]]]
```

To avoid lazy loading use this [library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

     NSString *imgurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseImgurl,[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgurl]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this line

```
cell.imageView.image = = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

as

```
cell.imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

One more thing you need to have image in your app bundle otherwise need to download the image in app caches folder then make path upto image and then try to load the image

Comment: I am sorry but i am really new at this. Do i need to add this also if so where?

Comment: NSData *img=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:img];